Finding consecutive bases for a Fermat pseudoprime
Is there a proof exists that determines how many consecutive bases can exist for a given pseudoprime.
Lets $n$ is a pseudoprime and for base $b$ where $1<b<n-1$ then $1 = b^{n-1}modn$
Lets say if n is also a pseudoprime w.r.t base $b+1$ then $1 = (b+1)^{n-1}modn$
Which implies when we substitute the 1st equation in 2nd we have an equation of this form
1 = $\frac{\binom{n-1}{0}}{(n-1)^{0}}$ + $\frac{\binom{n-1}{1}}{(n-1)^{1}}$ + ...+$1 mod n$
My question is can we represent this equation in some form and derive some meaning out of it to prove or disprove $\frac{\binom{n-1}{0}}{(n-1)^{0}}$ + $\frac{\binom{n-1}{1}}{(n-1)^{1}}$ + ...+$1 if the consecutive bases exists for the given pseudoprime or not.

Not sure what you want but Carmichael numbers $n$ satisfy $b^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$ for every base $b$ coprime to $n$.

true, in my case lets say if the number is prime power, i.e $n=p^k$, im using the enhanced MR test and expecting the outcome composite with a factor. But since there exists some base $b$ such that $n$ is a pseudoprime w.r.t that base. In which case I might get the outcome as probably prime, if the number of iterations are high enough the probability of getting the outcome as probably prime is significantly low for a given prime power number. My intention is to prove deterministically the given number of the form $n=p^k$ is of prime power, i,e composite with factor.

In order to do that, as I see the bases for a given number to be pseudoprime are not consecutive closer if the number is higher and base is some where close to the given number. So if I can prove there shouldn't exists two consecutive bases for which the number is not a pseudoprime then it surely be non-prime and non-carmichael.

Whether a given positive integer is a power of a prime (or just a perfect power) can efficiently be tested , for this we need no probable prime test

Using enhanced MR, though we test effectively but there is still a error probability of $4^{-k}$. Is there a test that is 100% effective in determining power of prime?


If a number has no special structure , a primality proof is expensive. Best known general methods in practice are the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely test (APR) and Elliptic-Curve-Proving (ECP) 2. If $N-1$ or $N+1$ can be fully factored or at least factored far enough , we can apply an efficient primality proof.



The $4^{-k}$  is the worst case scenario only occuring for very special numbers. If you have a "random" number and test it with a single fermat test with a random base (even the weak test is sufficient) , you get a very reliable test. 4. The BPSW-primality test is efficient (only a strong Fermat test and a Lucas test) and extremely reliable. No counterexample is known although infinite many are expected.


Understood, w.r.t to "random" number as input I learnt that the probability of a k-bit composite number passing t rounds is $P < k^2 4^{2-K^{1/2}}$ which is way less than $4^{-k}$, so like as you mentioned I ran one iteration of Miller Rabin on a composite number for about million times and all the time I see the results were consistent.
Will explore further on deterministic primality tests you suggested, thank you.
